# Quarkus mongodb integration

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus

I'm using quarkus to build an application that needs to connect to MongoDB.

However going over the documentation I could not find any module or guide that show me how can I do it:

https://quarkus.io/

There is a guide about hibernate and JPA, but nothing about mongodb.

Does anyone manage to do it? Can you share with me a repository with an example?

Comment: At this time there is no MongoDB support but I think there are plans to add it down the line. Supporting something in Quarkus means that steps are taken to ensure that it works in native mode as well, which is why you don't see support for the "whole world"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest versions of Quarkus have added MongoDB support.

https://quarkus.io/guides/mongo-guide

Answer (score 1):

I have use the following to access mongodb databases in some quarkus demo code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MongoClientFactory {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name="mongo.user")
    private String mongoUser;

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name="mongo.password")
    private String mongoPassword;

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name="mongo.host")
    private String mongoHost;

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name="mongo.port", defaultValue="27017")
    private int mongoPort;

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(defaultValue="admin")
    private String mongoAdminDb;

    private MongoClient mongoClient;
    private ServerAddress serverAddress;
    private MongoCredential mongoCredential;

    @PostConstruct
    void buildMongoClient() {
        logger.info("Building MongoClientFactory");
        serverAddress = new ServerAddress(mongoHost, mongoPort);
        mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUser, mongoAdminDb, mongoPassword.toCharArray());
    }

    @Produces
    public MongoClient produceMongoClient() {
        if (mongoClient == null) {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress, mongoCredential, MongoClientOptions.builder().build());
            logger.info("Connected to MongoDB server on {}:{}", mongoHost, mongoPort);
        }
        return mongoClient;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void cleanup() {
        if (mongoClient != null) {
            mongoClient.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Then I can just inject the client where ever needed:

```
public class SomBusinessObject {

    @Inject
    private MongoClient mongoClient;


    ...
}
```

The Mongo driver is added to the pom too:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I have not yet tested this with a native build. The standalone jar seems to run fine though.

**Update**

GraalVM Version 1.0.0-rc15 CE does not like the mongo driver. It seems to be impacted by [Error: No instances are allowed in the image heap for a class that is initialized or reinitialzied at image runtime: sun.security.provider.NativePRNG #712](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/712).

Additionally, the Quarkus dependency analyser appears to be sucking in `optional` dependencies, such as `com.github.jnr:jnr-unixsocket` and `org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java`.

Comment: Not a bad solution, but what about heartbeats and reconnect behavior. @micronautfw handles these things for you.

Comment: Current versions of the MongoDB java driver implement customisable heartbeats and connection pooling. My code is a little old as I had to support older versions of Mongo servers at the time I originally wrote it. The `MongoClientFactory` implementation was basically about exposing configuration. It was for a POC so it does not include all of the customisable behaviour that is provided by the java driver.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guide for MongoDB

https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb

You can use Panache also

https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache