# GraalVM: Quarkus + Mongo cannot find class

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, graalvm, quarkus

I had create a sample project using Quarkus and then I added a MongoDB.

For running using JVM everything works find, but when try to build a docker image using graalvm, I got the error bellow.

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ quarkus-backend ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/victor/sources/quarkus-mongo/target/quarkus-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:0.13.3:build (default) @ quarkus-backend ---
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Beginning quarkus augmentation
[INFO] [org.jboss.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.0.0.Alpha4
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Quarkus augmentation completed in 1615ms
[INFO] [io.quarkus.creator.phase.runnerjar.RunnerJarPhase] Building jar: /home/victor/sources/quarkus-mongo/target/quarkus-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:0.13.3:native-image (default) @ quarkus-backend ---
[INFO] [io.quarkus.creator.phase.nativeimage.NativeImagePhase] Running Quarkus native-image plugin on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
[INFO] [io.quarkus.creator.phase.nativeimage.NativeImagePhase] docker run -v /home/victor/sources/quarkus-mongo/target:/project:z --rm --user 1000:1000 quay.io/quarkus/centos-quarkus-native-image:graalvm-1.0.0-rc14 -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -jar quarkus-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -J-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1 -H:+PrintAnalysisCallTree -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http -H:-SpawnIsolates -H:-JNI --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace
[quarkus-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:9]    classlist:  10,109.77 ms
[quarkus-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:9]        (cap):   2,974.74 ms
[quarkus-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:9]        setup:   5,274.33 ms
21:14:26,482 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO version 3.7.0.Final
21:14:26,994 INFO  [org.xni.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.7.0.Final
21:14:32,218 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.0.0.Alpha4
[quarkus-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:9]     analysis:  35,833.87 ms
Printing call tree to /project/reports/call_tree_quarkus-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20190504_211458.txt
Printing list of used classes to /project/reports/used_classes_quarkus-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20190504_211501.txt
Printing list of used packages to /project/reports/used_packages_quarkus-backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner_20190504_211502.txt
Error: unsupported features in 6 methods
Detailed message:
Error: Class initialization failed: com.mongodb.UnixServerAddress
Original exception that caused the problem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jnr/unixsocket/UnixSocketAddress
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.ensureClassInitialized(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:199)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:162)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:138)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.maybeInitializeHosted(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:103)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.SVMHost.registerType(SVMHost.java:179)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.createType(AnalysisUniverse.java:263)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookupAllowUnresolved(AnalysisUniverse.java:204)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.WrappedConstantPool.lookupType(WrappedConstantPool.java:154)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupType(BytecodeParser.java:3992)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4235)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5023)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3184)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:2993)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:891)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:785)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:95)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:197)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:213)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:332)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.doParse(MethodTypeFlow.java:310)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureParsed(MethodTypeFlow.java:300)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.addContext(MethodTypeFlow.java:107)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.StaticInvokeTypeFlow.update(InvokeTypeFlow.java:346)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.BigBang$2.run(BigBang.java:508)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(CompletionExecutor.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketAddress
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 34 more
Error: Class initialization failed: com.mongodb.internal.connection.SnappyCompressor
Original exception that caused the problem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xerial/snappy/SnappyInputStream
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.ensureClassInitialized(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:199)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:162)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:138)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.maybeInitializeHosted(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:103)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.SVMHost.registerType(SVMHost.java:179)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.createType(AnalysisUniverse.java:263)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookupAllowUnresolved(AnalysisUniverse.java:204)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.WrappedConstantPool.lookupType(WrappedConstantPool.java:154)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupType(BytecodeParser.java:3992)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4235)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5023)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3184)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:2993)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:891)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:785)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:95)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:197)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:213)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:332)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.doParse(MethodTypeFlow.java:310)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureParsed(MethodTypeFlow.java:300)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.addContext(MethodTypeFlow.java:107)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.SpecialInvokeTypeFlow.onObservedUpdate(InvokeTypeFlow.java:421)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.notifyObservers(TypeFlow.java:352)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.update(TypeFlow.java:394)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.BigBang$2.run(BigBang.java:508)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(CompletionExecutor.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 36 more
Error: Class initialization failed: com.mongodb.internal.connection.UnixSocketChannelStream
Original exception that caused the problem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jnr/unixsocket/UnixSocketChannel
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.ensureClassInitialized(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:199)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:162)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.computeInitKindAndMaybeInitializeClass(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:138)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ClassInitializationSupportImpl.maybeInitializeHosted(ClassInitializationSupportImpl.java:103)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.SVMHost.registerType(SVMHost.java:179)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.createType(AnalysisUniverse.java:263)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisUniverse.lookupAllowUnresolved(AnalysisUniverse.java:204)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.infrastructure.WrappedConstantPool.lookupType(WrappedConstantPool.java:154)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.lookupType(BytecodeParser.java:3992)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.genNewInstance(BytecodeParser.java:4235)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBytecode(BytecodeParser.java:5023)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3184)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:2993)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:891)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:785)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:95)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:197)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
    at org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:213)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:332)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.doParse(MethodTypeFlow.java:310)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.ensureParsed(MethodTypeFlow.java:300)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.addContext(MethodTypeFlow.java:107)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.DefaultAnalysisPolicy$DefaultVirtualInvokeTypeFlow.onObservedUpdate(DefaultAnalysisPolicy.java:191)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.notifyObservers(TypeFlow.java:352)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.TypeFlow.update(TypeFlow.java:394)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.BigBang$2.run(BigBang.java:508)
    at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.CompletionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(CompletionExecutor.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 36 more
Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: com.mongodb.UnixServerAddress.<init>(java.lang.String). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
Trace: 
    at parsing com.mongodb.internal.connection.ServerAddressHelper.createServerAddress(ServerAddressHelper.java:31)
Call path from entry point to com.mongodb.internal.connection.ServerAddressHelper.createServerAddress(String, int): 
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ServerAddressHelper.createServerAddress(ServerAddressHelper.java:30)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ServerAddressHelper.createServerAddress(ServerAddressHelper.java:26)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultDnsSrvRecordMonitor$DnsSrvRecordMonitorRunnable.createServerAddressSet(DefaultDnsSrvRecordMonitor.java:124)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultDnsSrvRecordMonitor$DnsSrvRecordMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultDnsSrvRecordMonitor.java:78)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:473)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- WARNING: The above stack trace is not a real stack trace, it is a theoretical call tree---
-- If an interface has multiple implementations SVM will just display one potential call  ---
-- path to the interface. This is often meaningless, and what you actually need to know is---
-- the path to the constructor of the object that implements this interface.              ---
-- Quarkus has attempted to generate a more meaningful call flow analysis below          ---
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: com.mongodb.internal.connection.SnappyCompressor.<init>(). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
Trace: 
    at parsing com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.createCompressor(InternalStreamConnection.java:209)
Call path from entry point to com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.createCompressor(MongoCompressor): 
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.createCompressor(InternalStreamConnection.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.createCompressorMap(InternalStreamConnection.java:183)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.<init>(InternalStreamConnection.java:110)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionFactory.create(InternalStreamConnectionFactory.java:56)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:473)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- WARNING: The above stack trace is not a real stack trace, it is a theoretical call tree---
-- If an interface has multiple implementations SVM will just display one potential call  ---
-- path to the interface. This is often meaningless, and what you actually need to know is---
-- the path to the constructor of the object that implements this interface.              ---
-- Quarkus has attempted to generate a more meaningful call flow analysis below          ---
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved method during parsing: com.mongodb.internal.connection.UnixSocketChannelStream.<init>(com.mongodb.UnixServerAddress, com.mongodb.connection.SocketSettings, com.mongodb.connection.SslSettings, com.mongodb.connection.BufferProvider). To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing method is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
Trace: 
    at parsing com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamFactory.create(SocketStreamFactory.java:76)
Call path from entry point to com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamFactory.create(ServerAddress): 
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamFactory.create(SocketStreamFactory.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:124)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:473)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:193)
    at com.oracle.svm.core.code.IsolateEnterStub.PosixJavaThreads_pthreadStartRoutine_e1f4a8c0039f8337338252cd8734f63a79b5e3df(generated:0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- WARNING: The above stack trace is not a real stack trace, it is a theoretical call tree---
-- If an interface has multiple implementations SVM will just display one potential call  ---
-- path to the interface. This is often meaningless, and what you actually need to know is---
-- the path to the constructor of the object that implements this interface.              ---
-- Quarkus has attempted to generate a more meaningful call flow analysis below          ---
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
Error: Image building with exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:19 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-04T18:15:04-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.13.3:native-image (default) on project quarkus-backend: Failed to generate a native image: Failed to build native image: Image generation failed -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

How can fix this error? 
I tried add all dependencies to pom.xml, but it seems does not work.

To build the error, just run:

```
mvn package -Pnative -Dnative-image.docker-build=true
```

The code for testing can be found on the github [vepo/quarkus-mongo](https://github.com/vepo/quarkus-mongo)

Comment: It's not mongo, it's `jnr/unixsocket/UnixSocketAddress`.  Look into `com.github.jnr:jnr-unixsocket:0.22`

Comment: Yes, but mongodb depends on it. I do not see any reason to use that lib, but I see a reason to mongodb do not use it.

Comment: @K.Nicholas, I know the source of the problem. But no quarkus or mongodb developers cares for jnr-unixsocket. This is the question, if you read it. How to make Mongodb works with Quarkus. If you read the MongoDB driver pom.xml, this lib is optional, but GraalVM requires it, so the problem can be from GraalVM, how to tel Quarkus plugin to ignore it?

Comment: @Victor Quarkus doesn't yet have a code that "patches" the Mongo driver but this is on the roadmap: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/2048#issuecomment-483125417

Comment: @Victor, there is also more information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387611/quarkus-mongodb-integration. There are further SSL issues once the `jnr/unixsocket/UnixSocketAddress` issues are resolved